# elastic search DSL query python on string types

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

I have been trying really hard but struggling to get this right.
Actually in my Index mapping my all fields are type strings. e.g

```
{"ind_ecue_fin_ult1":{"mappings":{"ind_ecue_fin_ult1":{"properties":{"age":{"type":"string"},"altaDiff":{"type":"string"},"antiguedad":{"type":"string"},"canal_entrada":{"type":"string"},"cod_prov":{"type":"string"},"conyuemp":{"type":"string"},"empIndex":{"type":"string"},"fecDiff":{"type":"string"},"gender":{"type":"string"},"ind_actividad_cliente":{"type":"string"},"indext":{"type":"string"},"indfall":{"type":"string"},"indrel":{"type":"string"},"indrel_1mes":{"type":"string"},"indresi":{"type":"string"},"nomprov":{"type":"string"},"nuevo":{"type":"string"},"others":{"type":"string"},"renta":{"type":"string"},"residence":{"type":"string"},"segmento":{"type":"string"},"tiprel_1mes":{"type":"string"},"wt":{"type":"double"}}}}}}
```

I using python client for elasticsearch have generated the following query :

```
{'query': {'bool': {'minimum_should_match': 5,
   'should': [{'boost': 4, 'terms': {'age': '1'}},
    {'boost': 3, 'terms': {'antiguedad': '0.0'}},
    {'boost': 3.5, 'terms': {'indrel': '1'}},
    {'boost': 3, 'terms': {'indrel_1mes': '1'}},
    {'boost': 2, 'terms': {'tiprel_1mes': 'A'}},
    {'boost': 3, 'terms': {'indresi': 'S'}},
    {'boost': 2.5, 'terms': {'indext': 'N'}},
    {'boost': 2, 'terms': {'conyuemp': 'DEF'}},
    {'boost': 2, 'terms': {'canal_entrada': 'KHL'}},
    {'boost': 1.5, 'terms': {'indfall': 'N'}},
    {'boost': 1.5, 'terms': {'cod_prov': '28'}},
    {'boost': 2, 'terms': {'nomprov': 'MALAGA'}},
    {'boost': 1.5, 'terms': {'ind_actividad_cliente': '1'}},
    {'boost': 4, 'terms': {'renta': '1'}},
    {'boost': 2.5, 'terms': {'segmento': '02 - PARTICULARES'}},
    {'range': {'wt': {'boost': 5.0, 'gte': 0.4, 'lte': 0.525}}}]}}}
```

However, I am getting this exception even if I try on any one array term in "shoulds" :

```
curl -XPOST "htturl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ind_ahor_fin_ult1/_search" -d'
{"query": {"bool": {"minimum_should_match": 5,
   "should": [{"terms": {"renta": "1"},"boost": 4}]}}}'

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[terms] query does not support [renta]","index":"ind_ahor_fin_ult1","line":3,"col":35}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"ind_ahor_fin_ult1","node":"j20MAn_OQ9eRyNsrjf1MRQ","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[terms] query does not support [renta]","index":"ind_ahor_fin_ult1","line":3,"col":35}}]},"status":400}
```

please help. TIA.

Comment: the range query is working fine though, just that those string type queries isnt

Comment: curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ind_ahor_fin_ult1/_search" -d'
{"query": {"bool": {
   "should": {"match":{"segmento":"02 - PARTICULARES"}},"boost": 1}}}', lemme see if I can stitch the array too in should

Comment: curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ind_ahor_fin_ult1/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { "match": { "segmento":  "02 - PARTICULARES" }},
                { "match": { "renta": "1"   }}
            ]
        }
    }
}' This has worked too, just that I am failing to know where to put the boost param.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out, the right syntax is below :

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ind_ahor_fin_ult1/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { "match": { "segmento":  {"query":"02 - PARTICULARES","boost":2}}},
                { "match": { "renta": {"query":"1","boost":3}}}
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 2
        }
    }
}'
```

It was very well described on  :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html

I had missed it, somehow. Thanks!